# SELECT GROUP POR LOJA

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia!

galera tenho 4 lojas a 1,2,3,4 quero consultar a ultima venda de um produto de cada loja.trazendo somente as ultimas 4 vendas, porém uma de cada loja. alguém pode me ajudar?

```
select top 4 io.CodLoja,io.NumOrc,MAX(datafechamento) 
from ItensOrcamento io 
  inner join Orcamento o on io.CodLoja = o.CodLoja and 
                            io.NumOrc = o.NumOrc 
where io.CodProd = 4446 
and o.Fechado = 2
group by io.CodLoja,io.NumOrc,o.DataFechamento 
order by o.DataFechamento desc
```

Comment: Informe o SGBD pois este limite difere por Banco.

Comment: Desculpe sql server

Comment: Não tem sentido você colocar `o.DataFechamento` em sua cláusula GROUP BY se você está utilizando este campo na função de agregação (MAX). Se você quer apenas por loja por qual motivo está incluindo `io.NumOrc` na query?

Comment: preciso dessas informações, o numero do pedido pode ser igual mas em lojas diferentes. esse select que coloquei foi o ultimo que tentei, mas não consegui ainda.
LOJA PEDIDO VALOR
  1             10 50
  2             10 55
  3             15 60
  4             20 48

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você utilizar um `WITH` em conjunto com `ROW_NUMBER` para obter o dado mais recente:

```
WITH vendas AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY io.codloja ORDER BY o.datafechamento DESC) AS posicao
         io.CodLoja,
         io.NumOrc,
         o.datafechamento
  INNER JOIN Orcamento o
          ON io.CodLoja = o.CodLoja
         AND io.NumOrc = o.NumOrc
  WHERE io.CodProd = 4446 
    AND o.Fechado = 2
)
SELECT v.codloja,
       v.numorc,
       v.datafechamento
  FROM vendas v
 WHERE posicao = 1
```

---

> [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna o número sequencial de uma linha em uma partição de um conjunto de resultados, iniciando em 1 para a primeira linha de cada partição.

Comment: Deu certinho obrigado